# Mail forwarding to external domain - BT, Exchange 2010

Tags: email, exchange, smtp

Thanks in advance for any help, this is not a basic mail forwarding question there is in fact a twist.

We are trying to forward mail from an address at our domain john.example@ourdomain.com to another domain john.example@anotherdomain.com these domains have no kind of trusts or connections.

We set up the basic mail forwarding inside Exchange 2010, using the Recipient Configuration>MailContact>New Mail Contact by creating a new contact pointing to our external destination address.

After this we then change the Delivery Options on the john.example@ourdomain.com mailbox to forward mail to this contact, it is also set to retain a copy in the local mailbox.

Now when we send a message to john.example@ourdomian.com it gets to the Exchange account, but it then gets a bounce back of

[image]

But the twist is, the message arrives at the destination at john.example@anotherdomain.com but it has the bounce back in the header.

Could this be an Exchange misconfiguration, Bt says its not them. But the bounce back does say its getting rejected by mail.btconnect.com

Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

Error: 550 Mail.BTConnect.com not permitted

You need to add the sending domain to BT Mail Relay. You might have to call them up.

See a similar discussion here.
http://business.forums.bt.com/t5/Email/550-Not-Permitted/td-p/17411